# date on a ggplot graph not in a correct order

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am new here in this community and I have started to work with R for my university study. I have a problem with creating a graph which I can't solve by myself.
I would like to create a line graph (x-axis: date, y-axis: number of sightings). The graph didn't show the date in a correct order. It starts with 1th August and it ends with 30th July. The date is in the Excel file already in a correct order. 
I tried this:

```
number_sigthings$date = as.Date(number_sightings$date, format = "%d.%m%.%y")
number_sightings$date <- factor(number_sightings$date, ordered = T)
```

But both didn't help to solve the problem.

I would be very glad if someone can help me. Thank you very much.

Here is my script which I wrote:

```
options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

input1 <- "C:\\Users\\Hannah\\Documents\\Meeresbiologie\\Projekt Stella\\Daten Dänemark\\Dänemark Theodolitmessungen\\number_sightings.csv"

number_sightings <- read.csv(input1, sep=";")
library (lubridate)
library(ggplot2)

number_sigthings$date = as.Date(number_sightings$date, format = "%d.%m%.%y")

number_sightings$date <- factor(number_sightings$date, ordered = T)
plot <-ggplot(number_sightings, aes(x=date, y=number, group=1)) + geom_point(stat="identity") + geom_line(linetype="dashed")

plot <- plot +  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white"))
plot <- plot + theme(panel.grid.minor=element_blank())
plot <- plot + theme(panel.grid.minor.x=element_blank(),panel.grid.major.x=element_blank())
plot <- plot + scale_x_date(breaks=seq("30.07.18, 02.09.18"),expand=c(0,0), labels=date_format("%d.%m.%y"), date_breaks = "1 day", date_minor_breaks = "1 day")
plot <- plot+ggtitle("")+(ylab("number of harbour porpoise sightings/hour"))
print(plot)
```

I wrote this in my script after the input of my csv file.

> dput(number_sightings)
>   structure(list(date = c("31.07.2018", "01.08.2018", "02.08.2018", 
>   "03.08.2018", "06.08.2018", "07.08.2018", "08.08.2018", "09.08.2018", 
>   "13.08.2018", "15.08.2018", "17.08.2018", "22.08.2018", "23.08.2018", 
>   "24.08.2018", "25.08.2018"), number = c(2.7, 0.99, 2.11, 1.63, 
>   1.16, 1, 3.57, 1, 1.84, 3.25, 2.25, 2, 1.88, 2.67, 3.04)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
>   -15L))

Comment: It would be helpful if you provide the data, by using `dput(number_sightings)` after you read in the data.

Comment: You don't need this line: `factor(number_sightings$date, ordered = T)` , once you convert the column into a Date object, leave it as a Date object.  See the comment above about providing a sample of your data.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I wrote dput(number_sightings) in my script and it shows me the dates and the numbers in a correct order, but the graph didn't change the dates. Do you have another idea what I could do?

Comment: Edit your post above and include the output of `dput(number_sightings)` or `dput(head(number_sightings))`.

Comment: Ok,thank you. I missunderstood it after the first reading but now I get it and I edited my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One needs to make sure when converting from character to Date, that the format option matches the format of the text.

```
library(ggplot2)
#test data
number_sightings<-structure(list(date = c("31.07.2018", "01.08.2018", "02.08.2018", "03.08.2018", "06.08.2018", "07.08.2018", "08.08.2018", "09.08.2018", "13.08.2018", "15.08.2018", "17.08.2018", "22.08.2018", "23.08.2018", "24.08.2018", "25.08.2018"), number = c(2.7, 0.99, 2.11, 1.63, 1.16, 1, 3.57, 1, 1.84, 3.25, 2.25, 2, 1.88, 2.67, 3.04)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -15L))

#convert from character to Date Object (notice the format string)
number_sightings$date = as.Date(number_sightings$date, format = "%d.%m.%Y")

#number_sightings$date <- factor(number_sightings$date, ordered = T)
plot <-ggplot(number_sightings, aes(x=date, y=number, group=1)) + geom_point(stat="identity") + geom_line(linetype="dashed")

plot <- plot +  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white"))
plot <- plot + theme(panel.grid.minor=element_blank())
plot <- plot + theme(panel.grid.minor.x=element_blank(),panel.grid.major.x=element_blank())

#Corrected this line (%y for 2 digit year, %Y or 4 digit year)
plot <- plot + scale_x_date(expand=c(0,0), date_labels=("%d.%m.%y"), date_breaks = "4 day")
plot <- plot+ggtitle("")+(ylab("number of harbour porpoise sightings/hour"))
print(plot)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(ggplot2)
#test data
number_sightings<-structure(list(date = c("31.07.2018", "01.08.2018", "02.08.2018", "03.08.2018", "06.08.2018", "07.08.2018", "08.08.2018", "09.08.2018", "13.08.2018", "15.08.2018", "17.08.2018", "22.08.2018", "23.08.2018", "24.08.2018", "25.08.2018"), number = c(2.7, 0.99, 2.11, 1.63, 1.16, 1, 3.57, 1, 1.84, 3.25, 2.25, 2, 1.88, 2.67, 3.04)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -15L))

#convert from character to Date Object (notice the format string)
number_sightings$date = as.Date(number_sightings$date, format = "%d.%m.%Y")

#number_sightings$date <- factor(number_sightings$date, ordered = T)
plot <-ggplot(number_sightings, aes(x=date, y=number, group=1)) + geom_point(stat="identity") + geom_line(linetype="dashed")

plot <- plot +  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white"))
plot <- plot + theme(panel.grid.minor=element_blank())
plot <- plot + theme(panel.grid.minor.x=element_blank(),panel.grid.major.x=element_blank())

#Corrected this line (%y for 2 digit year, %Y or 4 digit year)
plot <- plot + scale_x_date(expand=c(0,0), date_labels=("%d.%m.%y"), date_breaks = "4 day")
plot <- plot+ggtitle("")+(ylab("number of harbour porpoise sightings/hour"))
print(plot)
```